# Oracle JET : Unable to build ojet hybrid project after upgrading xcode to Version 12.0 (12A7209)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, oracle-jet

This morning I updated my xcode to Version 12.0 (12A7209) and since then I am not able to build the project for ios

### Replication steps

```sh
ojet create testapp --template=navbar
cd testapp 
ojet add hybrid 
ojet  build ios
```

Getting the below error

```sh
.........
In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/hellonuh/Desktop/testapp/hybrid/platforms/ios/build/emulator/include/Cordova/CDVAppDelegate.h:20:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURL.h:595:1: note: 'stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (nullable NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc API_DEPRECATED("Use -stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid.", macos(10.0,10.11), ios(2.0,9.0), watchos(2.0,2.0), tvos(9.0,9.0));
^
3 warnings and 3 errors generated.


Cordova compile finished.
Error: Error: Command failed: cordova compile ios --debug --emulator
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/hellonuh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp-hfsgwahghfnpzecdcshskgzlpyep/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine.o /Users/hellonuh/Desktop/testapp/hybrid/platforms/ios/testapp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/CDVWKWebViewEngine.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

Please help

Comment: @peppertech Can you look into this issue.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?